# Test NSInteger in an if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, uidatepicker, nsinteger

I Have an if statement that is testing a that a UIDatepicker date is not being selected outside of a certain set of hours. E.g:

```
if (hour < 9 || hour >= 17 || (hour >= 17 && minute > 30))
```

I now need to find out how to test that my NSInteger *day is not being selected before the system dates day (you cant select a date in the past). But when i add my condition in i get an error saying that the statement cant test the condition due to the fact there is no int value there. See below code:

```
if (hour < 9 || hour >= 17 || (hour >= 17 && minute > 30) || day < sysdate)
```

Thanks.

Comment: set min and max dates to UIDatePicker

Comment: you can use `datePiker.minimumDate` and `datePiker.maximumDate` . so user can select only that time.

Comment: If day is a pointer to an NSInteger you should dereference it before comparing it to an integer (I.e. *day < sysdate)

Comment: do u want to fix the time interval for today only or on all days

Comment: Show us the declaration of `day`, and how you set it.

Answer (score 0):

You refer to day as being an `NSInteger*`. If that's the case you want to dereference it before comparing it to sysdate. I.e. You need to write the last part of your condition as: `*day < sysdate`